# Dart immutable object with immutable list

Tags: dart, constructor, constants

I am trying to create a class that is immutable, since it is a sort of `EventArgs` class. I want to know how `const` and `immutable` I can make my fields. This is what I have so far:

```dart
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

@immutable
class ConnectedDevicesChangedEventArgs {
  final Iterable<String> devices;

  const ConnectedDevicesChangedEventArgs(Iterable<String> d)
      : devices = const List.unmodifiable(d); // error on const
}
```

I get an error saying:

> The constructor being called isn't a const constructor.
> Try removing 'const' from the constructor invocation.dartconst_with_non_const

I have the following requirements:

- Anyone accessing the `EventArgs` class is not allowed to change `devices`
- Anyone accessing the `EventArgs` class is not allowed to add/remove anything from the `devices`
- `devices` will simply never change

Is it a good practice to make this constructor `const`, since there is only a `final` variable?

I have read this: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#constant-constructors

Comment: I have been trying out a bit more, and I guess I would just use a non-const constructor in this case. I will keep List.unmodifiable, because it forces an immutable list. Even when someone tries to cast the devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `final List.unmodifyable()` can neither be change to a different list, not have the list itself modified.

However, it does not satisfy Dart's requirements for a `const` constructor, which states that the entire instance can be computed at compile time.

In this case, you can simply omit the `const` keyword.